# When I call startActivity() for an Intent in Android Studio, my app keeps stopping

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I'm practising Intent in Android development where I click a button in the MainActivity to start another Activity. But for some reason the demo app keeps stopping and exit whenever the Intent is called. My code nearly resemble the one from the instructions on the Internet. What could be the problems here?

Here is the MainActivity code:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btnNext = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnNext)
        btnNext.setOnClickListener {
            val i = Intent(this, Activity2::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Activity2 started from MainActivity:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class Activity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2)
    }
}
```

I tried to change API version but it doesn't work

Comment: _"the demo app keeps stopping and exit"_. So you need to examine the stacktrace in the logcat output.

Comment: Pl. paste the stacktrace. Also, is the `Activity2` added in the `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Update your question along with stacktrace fatal eror.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Answer (score 1):

This Typically happens when you add activity like normal classess , in this case you will forget to add the activity in Manifest file.

Also please try to debug the issue if possible , like removing the click listner and start activity directly

and make a habbit to see the crash logs in terminal , it helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after checking logcat, I figure out the problem resides in the Theme. My newly created Activity2 has no Theme and I have to manually assign it with a AppCompat theme or its descendant.
Here is the correct Activity2 manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activity2"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

However, I can't reuse Theme.MyApplication like the MainActivity, which will cause the same bug. Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Pretty strange that you have to specify a theme. Activities dont need a theme. Specify a theme in the `<application  ` tag.